# Mobile iOS Safari Test URL Scheme JS

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari, url-scheme

**Aim:**
What I wish to do is test if a URL scheme (Cydia://) exists on the device, and then report back to a variable. I do not want to actually open the URL.

*I've done a load of googling, all the answers I can find actually open the URL scheme.*

---

**Update:**

I've been testing a few methods:

```
Ajax Call - Fails with and without URL Scheme existing - Returns "error"
Load Fake Script from URL Scheme - Fails w/ & w/o URL Scheme existing - Returns "error"
```

I have contacted the author of the app that uses the URL Scheme to see if he has any resources on the scheme that I could load to test if it exists, but I've had no reply yet.

---

Thanks.